# How to BCP export three related tables in a transaction consistent manner?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, bcp

Have three related tables that I would like to bcp export to file(s).  This three tables have relationships to each other.  Is there a good way to bcp export these tables in a transactionally consistent manner?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

how about creating a database snapshot and then running the BCP against that ?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/create-a-database-snapshot-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: How do you instruct bcp to connect to the snapshot?

Comment: A database snapshot has its own database name.